# Create new array in Laravel blade to create array within request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I need to create a new array inside a blade and then post it within a request, but it just keeps spitting out the id's as key value pairs.

I need a named array that I can specifically target and iterate through... any suggestion??

```
@foreach ($allTheAgreements as $agreement)
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="{{$agreementID[] = $agreement->id}}" id="{{ $agreement->id }}" 
        value="{{ $agreement->id }}">
        </td>
        <td>{{ $agreement->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $agreement->agreement_type }}</td>
        <td>Agreement Status</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

[image]

So how do I initialise a new array within a blade template input element and get the indexed values back?

Something like

```
$arrayWithinRequest[] = [ 0 => '2', 1 => '5', 2 => '7'};
```

Comment: Try `<input type="checkbox" name="agreements[{{$agreement->id}}]" id="{{ $agreement->id }}" value="{{ $agreement->id }}">`

Comment: That's done it, so simple, so eligant haha, thank you my friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<input type="checkbox" name="agreements[{{$agreement->id}}]" id="{{ $agreement->id }}" value="{{ $agreement->id }}">
```